# Selectize config onChange option

Tags: angularjs, config, selectize.js

AngularJS 1.4, selectize 3.0
How get old(previous) value in **onChange** section? 
Several arguments in function didn't help

```
 Config = {
              maxItems: 1,=
              valueField: 'name',
              labelField: 'name',
              onChange: function(name) {
                //code here
              },
              onItemRemove: function(name) {
                //didn't help
              },
            };
```

Comment: adding additional variable for directive not an option(difficult logic)

Comment: You should look at https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md